# best way to track time for create and update in SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

i have a website that uses nhibernate to speak to SQL Server 2005.

I now want every record to have a createdDateTime and lastUpdatedDateTime field.  Where should this value be set. i am worries about things like timezones, consistency, etc . .  any thoughts on the options below:

1. Inside my application code (right before i do a write)
2. Inside SQL Server (using triggers or other functions)
3. Other ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are best handled [directly by SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610370/question-about-datecreated-and-datemodified-columns-sql-server) to ensure true data integrity. As far as consistency is concerned, the server time will be used so there shouldn't be problems. You could use UTC time in SQL Server as @gbn suggests in the comments.

Comment: I'd add you can use UTC time in SQL Server too

Comment: @gbn, good point, I've updated my answer to take it into account.

Answer (score 1):

although Darin Dimitrov's answer is perfectly valid you must take into account if you want the relevant DateTime fields to reflect business-logic consistency:

Using a DB-only approach you would have to use the GetDate() function which will be different for each row inserted. For rather larger insert sets you will have variably different timestamps set for the first and last item inserted.

If you do it in your application you can assign the same DateTime value for all inserted/updated items.

**This may or may not be of importance to you, it depends on your needs**.

In a web application and a transaction-per-request pattern this makes sense as you can distinctively track what each request did in the database, perhaps for reporting reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NHibernate events. They work pretty well, and although I agree that auditing is usually better handled by Sql Server itself, it's always nice to have the option. You can see a full tutorial [here](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/creating-an-audit-log-using-nhibernate-events.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you update the LastUpdateTime through code like DateTime.Now then it will take the server's DateTime .At this phase only the server timezone will be considered.

If you really want to consider clients timezone better use javascript to pass the clients datetime and zone .Have a zone field too in the table columns and update the zone for correct datetiem manioulation.

Sql Server have a good data type for TimeZone .So you can have a column like that. Please refer below link.

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dev/datetime_2008_p1.aspx